# Serial output not transferring to file (using processing)

Tags: arduino, processing

I am having trouble saving Arduino sensor data to a text file. I am writing the sensor data to the serial port and using processing program that reads that data from the serial port and writing it to a file.

This is the code am I using for the processing.

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial mySerial;
PrintWriter output;
void setup() {
   mySerial = new Serial( this, Serial.list()[0], 9600 );
   output = createWriter( "data.txt" );
}
void draw() {
    if (mySerial.available() > 0 ) {
         String value = mySerial.readString();
         if ( value != null ) {
              output.println( value );
         }
    }
}

void keyPressed() {
    output.flush();  // Writes the remaining data to the file
    output.close();  // Finishes the file
    exit();  // Stops the program
}
```

The data isn't transferring from my Arduino serial monitor to the .txt file. After I have gathered quite a bit of data from the Arduino sensor, the file is still empty. Is there a specific order of running the Arduino code or the processing code first? What else could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As you're saying that :

> After I have gathered quite a bit of data from the Arduino sensor, the file is still empty.

I assume that you're monitoring the serial output of the Arduino via the Arduino IDE serial console. But the serial protocol can't "feed" both the Arduino IDE console AND you Processing script.

So did you try to run the Arduino and the Processing script without opening the serial console ?

**EDIT:**

And of course is your baudrate (**9600**) matching between your Arduino and your Processing script ?

```
mySerial = new Serial( this, Serial.list()[0], 9600 );
```

**EDIT #2:**
In the setup() part of the code, you're defining which serial port you wan't to listen : (The first item of the `Serial.list()` array)

```
mySerial = new Serial( this, Serial.list()[0], 9600 );
```

But, on Os X for example, Serial.list()[0] is the bluetooth incoming port.

What I did was printing the full `Serial.list()` array by adding

```
print(Serial.list());
```

just after the `void setup() {`

The you can read in the Processing console the port list, mine was :

```
/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port /dev/cu.usbmodem1411 /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port /dev/tty.usbmodem1411
```

Because you want to listen from the Arduino (`cu.usbmodem1411`), you need to set modify `mySerial` to adress the second item of the array as follow :

```
mySerial = new Serial( this, Serial.list()[1], 9600 );
```

Comment: I run the programs separately. First I run the Arduino code, then the Processing. It won't even allow me to run them both simultaneously as the port is "busy" while I upload one of the codes. I am familiar with Arduino, but I have never used Processing before, so perhaps I'm just not understanding the code or not using the program correctly. And yes, both my baud rates are 9600 in my Arduino and Processing code.

Comment: I found an answered, see "EDIT #2" par above.

Comment: Also, a little precision, when clicking on the arrow on the Arduino IDE you're uploading the sketch to your Arduino board, and not "running" it. Then, when the code is uploaded into the board, it runs continuously while the Arduino is powered up.